# how to get the path of current open folder without using terminal?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I have searched this question for a while, but no exact answer on it.

I want to create a custom shortcut that can open the current directory in terminal.

So how can I get the path without using terminal?

**Simplify the question:** I know right click the target folder and select open in terminal can open this folder in a terminal. I want to create a custom shortcut instead of this action.

Comment: What is "DIY"? What is " the folder of current window "?

Comment: You might want to clarify a bit. What you describe seems simply "open terminal here", but again it doesn't.

Comment: You could use the file manager **Thunar** instead of Nautilus, wich I assume you currently use, that shows the current path at every moment.

Comment: *I want to create a custom shortcut that can open the current directory in terminal.*

*So how can I get the path without using terminal?* --> Contradiction

Comment: M. Becerra: I mean open a folder, then use shortcut to open this folder in a terminal.

Comment: If you are using Nautilus, there is an add-on to do it. I have it installed. There is an option on right mouse button to open in a terminal.

Comment: To Pilot6: many thanks! I will check it out. Yes, using shortcut of right click by F10 and click open in terminal is also nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

**To get the path of current open folder without using terminal**

Right click on folder and click on `Properties` option.

[image]

And you'll get location of folder in `Basic` tab.

[image]